# parser code of Octave?

Tags: parsing, open-source, octave

i would like to work on parser code of Octave. I have cloned the central repo of Octave and got only some idea about where the actual parser code can be. 
Although i am just lost as where to start from? 
Where exactly can i get the parer code of Octave?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't get the impression you've actually looked very hard.  Why is it that you can't find the actual parser in thier code base?

Answer (score 1):

In the development branch, the file you are looking for is `/libinterp/parse-tree/oct-parse.yy`. Note that the source tree has been changed in this branch so will be in a different location if you are working on the stable branch. But if you plan on contributing you should be working on the development branch anyway.